# what is the verb tense for "is repaired" in this sentence

Tags: verbs, tenses

what is the verb tense for "is repaired" in the sentence "they will be eating breakfast in the local cafe until their kitchen ***is repaired***".

Comment: _Is_ (and any cluster of verbs following _is_) can **always** be called present tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... present tense, passive form